# Can you have more than one subquery in a where clause?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, sql-in

I don't have an example for this but I was just wondering if something like this is valid in any situation:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE something1 IN (SELECT somefield2 FROM sometable2)
  AND something2 IN (SELECT somefield3 FROM sometable3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your syntax needs to be fixed though:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE something1 IN (SELECT somefield2 FROM sometable2)                        
AND something2 IN (SELECT somefield3 FROM sometable3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. You can have as many conditions as you want in a `where` clause, regardless of whether they have `in` conditions or not.

Comment: Keep in mind one thing, however.  While you can have as many conditions/sub-querys as possible, you can and will hit performance issues.

Comment: @Leptonator views dont affect the performances unless they are materialized which is not possible in most RDBMS

Comment: @ThomasG - have just removed my reference to views.